# Print Customer Attribute In Order, Invoice and PDF. Kindly Help me. In Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I have created a customer attribute process given below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I required to get the customer attribute Order, Invoice and PDF Reports like below
[image]

Comment: Did you enter the new attribute value in Customer Edit from Admin?

Comment: Also, please make sure that you make a new order, old orders won't have the new attribute

Comment: Yes I have entered a new attribute value in Customer Edit from Admin It's new order